# SQL query views vs joins?

Tags: sql

I have a noob SQL question. I have this table, with a query attached https://www.mycompiler.io/view/BhSdU94MdsD

```
-- INIT database
CREATE TABLE Product 
(
    ProductID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Name TEXT,
    TimeScale INTEGER,
    CreatedTime Integer
);

INSERT INTO Product(Name, Timescale, CreatedTime) VALUES ("foo", 1, 101);
INSERT INTO Product(Name, Timescale, CreatedTime) VALUES ("bar", 2, 1500);
```

Basically, every product has a name, timescale, and created time associated with it. Each product has a "lag". This is computed as the difference between the created time and a threshold associated with the timescale.

A timescale of 1 has a threshold of 100, so the products with timescale=1 will have a lag of: CreatedTime - 100.

Similarly, a timescale of 2 has a threshold of 1000, so those
products will have a lag of: CreatedTime - 1000.

What I'd like to do is write a query that order all products by their associated lag. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I feel like I need to create a view to compute the "lag" column, but not sure if that's the best way forward

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The syntax above isn't ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case` expression to calculate the `lag` depending on the timescale.

```
select
  *,
  case Timescale
    when 1 then CreatedTime - 100
    when 2 then CreatedTime - 1000
    else null
  end as "lag"
from Product
```

---

If you use this frequently, you can [create a view](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) for convenience.

```
create view product_lag as
select
  *,
  case Timescale
    when 1 then CreatedTime - 100
    when 2 then CreatedTime - 1000
    else null
  end as "lag"
from Product;

select * from product_lag;
```

Or you can add a [virtual or generated column](https://sqlite.org/gencol.html) where you declare a column which is automatically generated from other columns.

```
alter table product add column "lag" integer generated always as (
  case timescale
    when 1 then CreatedTime - 100
    when 2 then CreatedTime - 1000
    else null
  end
);
```

[Demonstration](https://www.mycompiler.io/new/sql?fork=BhSdU94MdsD) and thank you for providing a workspace.

Comment: Thank you - this is amazing. Just for my further understanding, what are efficiency tradeoffs between the options? Feel free to point me to any relevant links

Comment: The first and the second one incurr in the same extra computational effort (although minimal). The second one is easier to write if you are using that lag value oftern. The third one stores the lag; that is consumes more space, but it's computed only once.

Comment: @TheImpaler They all do the same work., The generated column is not stored, it is virtual. SQLite does not allow adding stored generated columns after table creation.

Comment: @nz_21 None, they all do the same thing. You can verify with `explain`. In general, simple math like this isn't a performance concern. It becomes a concern if you search on it because it's not indexed, a table scan will be required. (The Impaler is referring to a *stored* generated column, which can be indexed, but this one must be virtual because we added it; a SQLite restriction.)

Comment: @Schwern Oops... I didn't notice it was SQLite.

Comment: Note that `case` is an _expression_, not statement.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this case would need further reference to map the timescale to its respective lag (i.e. 100, 1000).

If there's only one or two timescales, then a simple `case when` should be sufficient to get the lag.

If there are more, another table as the mapping reference could be useful. However, if a table creation is to be avoided, then another option would be introducing the logic in a CTE or subquery to enhance more data to get the lag and its timescale.

All and all, after successfully map the timescale to its respective lag by join to the table / cte / subquery (or no need for joins at all if `case when` to be implemented), then a `timediff` (or similar) function would be able to calculate the time from the lag.

Which then could be materialized as a view if this query would be useful from time to time.